# Horizontal Sobolev space on Carnot group

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, sub-riemannian-geometry, heisenberg-groups

This question is connected with my previous: [Heisenberg group: function without vertical derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/q/204537/15946). 
Here I am trying to look from another side: what is a difference between Sobolev space and horizontal Sobolev space on Carnot group?

Outline some notations.

A **Carnot group** $\mathbb G$ is a connected simply-connected nilpotent Lie group hose Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is graded: $\mathfrak{g} = V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_m$, и
$[V_1,V_j]=V_{j+1}$ provided $j=1,\ldots, m-1$, and $[V_1,V_m] = \{0\}$.

$V_1$ is horizontal subbundle, $X_1, \dots X_n$ - basis of $V_1$ and 
$X_1, \dots X_n, X_{21}, \dots X_{2n_2},\cdots X_{m1}, \dots X_{mn_m}$ - basis of $\mathfrak g$.

**Derivatives.** A locally summable function $v$ is called the generalized
derivative of $f$ along the vector field X, whenever
$$
\int v\psi\, dx = -\int f X\psi\, dx,
$$
for every $\psi\in C^{\infty}_0$. We denote $v = Xf$.

**Sobolev spaces.**

- The horizontal Sobolev space $HW^1_p$ consists of all locally summable functions of finite norm
  $$
  \|f \mid HW^1_p\| = \left(\int |f|^p\, dx \right)^{\frac1p} +
  \left(\int |\nabla_{\mathcal L}f|^p\, dx \right)^{\frac1p}, 
  $$
  where $\nabla_{\mathcal L}f = (X_1f, \dots X_nf)$ is the generalized subgradient of $f$ at x ∈ D which uses only the derivatives along the horizontal fields.
- The Sobolev space $W^1_p$ consists of all locally summable functions of finite norm
  $$
  \|f \mid W^1_p\| = \left(\int |f|^p\, dx \right)^{\frac1p} +
  \left(\int |\nabla f|^p\, dx \right)^{\frac1p}, 
  $$
  where $\nabla_{\mathcal L}f = (X_1f, \dots X_nf, X_{21}f, \dots X_{2n_2}f,\cdots X_{m1}f, \dots X_{mn_m}f)$.

It is clear that if $f\in W^1_p$ then $f\in HW^1_p$. 
The question is following: if there is a function $f\in HW^1_p$ such that  $f\not\in W^1_p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V_1 \ne \mathfrak{g}$, then $H W^{1, p} \ne W^{1, p}$.

The construction is based on the notion of dilation on the Carnot group $\mathbb{G}$. The dilation $\delta_r$ is defined by for $X \in V_i$ by
$$
\delta_r \exp (t X) = \exp (i \log r X).
$$
This dilation is an automorphism on $\mathbb{G}$.

If $\mu$ is the Haar measure on the group $\mathbb{G}$, then 
$$
\mu (\delta_r (A)) = r^Q\mu (A),
$$
where
$$
  Q = \sum_{i = 1}^m i \dim V_i.
$$

We now choose a function $\varphi \in C^\infty (\mathbb{G})$ such that $\varphi = 1$ on some compact set $K$ and $\varphi = 0$ in $\mathbb{G} \setminus \delta_2 K$.

One has then, if $X \in V_i$,
$$
  \int_{G} \vert X (\varphi \circ \delta_r^{-1})\vert^p \,\mathrm{d}\mu
= r^{Q - pi} \int_{G} \vert X \varphi \vert^p \,\mathrm{d}\mu.
$$

Therefore, if we let $f = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j \varphi \circ \delta_{2^{-j}}^{-1}$, we have
$$
  \int_{G} \vert X f \vert^p 
= \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \vert a_j\vert^p 2^{j (pi - Q)} \int_{G} \vert X \varphi \vert^p \,\mathrm{d}\mu.
$$
The required counterexample is obtained by choosing the sequence $(a_j)_{j \ge  0}$ in such a way that 
$$
  \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \vert a_j\vert^p 2^{j (p - Q)} 
< \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \vert a_j\vert^p 2^{j (2p - Q)} = \infty,
$$
for example
$$
  a_j = 2^{-j (2 - Q / p)}.
$$

Comment: Should the next to last equation be following $$\sum_{j = 0}^\infty \vert a_j\vert^p 2^{j (pi - Q)} 
> \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \vert a_j\vert^p 2^{j (2p - Q)} = \infty ?$$

Comment: No, the left-hand side corresponds to $\int_{\mathbb{G}} \vert \nabla_{\mathcal{L}} f\vert_{L^p}$ and the righ-hand side to  $\int_{\mathbb{G}} \vert \nabla f\vert_{L^p}$.